# Format validation error message as nested associative array

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5.7

I have a Json object of data as shown below

```
{
  "name": "something",
  "location": {
    "city": "some where",
    "country": "some where",

  }
}
```

Rule used to validate Request is

```
[
    'name' => 'required',
    'location.city' => 'required',
    'location.country' => 'required'
]
```

Which returns error message like

```
{
  "name": [
    "The name field is required."
  ],
  "location.city": [
    "The location.city field is required."
  ],
  "location.county": [
    "The location.country field is required."
  ]
}
```

How can I format error message as a nested array like the Request.

```
{
  "name": [
    "The name field is required."
  ],
  "location": {
    "city": [
      "The city field is required"
    ],
    "country": [
      "The country field is required"
    ]
  }
}
```

Any default methods available ?
I am using `Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who looking for the solution This is how I implemented

```
<?php 
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\HttpResponseException;

class UserStoreRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required',
            'location.city' => 'required'
            'location.country' => 'required'
        ];
    }
    public function attributes()
    {
        return [
            'location.city' => 'City'
            'location.country' => 'Country'
        ];
    }
    protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
    {
        $errors = $validator->errors()->getMessages();
        $errors_formated = array();
        foreach ($errors as $key => $value) {
        array_set($errors_formated, $key, $value);
        }
        throw new HttpResponseException(response()->json(['error' => $errors_formated], 422));
    }
}
```

The result of `$validator->errors()->getMessages()` is just like `array_dot()` helper function result. So I did the Opposite of `array_dot()`, also altered my attribute name into pretty name

Comment: i got errors: Undefined function array_set

Answer (score 1):

In your case , you need to build the error message yourself. you can still use the default messages in the `ressources/lang/en/validation` messages file.

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'name' => 'required',
    'location.city' => 'required',
    'location.country' => 'required'
]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    return response()->json($yourOwnFormat,422);
    //you can use $validator->errors() to build it
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Is it?** [Laravel Documentation- Customizing the Error Messages](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#customizing-the-error-messages)

```
public function messages()
{
    return [
        'location.city' => 'The city field is required',
        'location.county'  => 'The county field is required',
    ];
}
```

Comment: It will only change the message part like `The city field is required` I need to change the key `location.city`. Please have a look at my response sample